# Applications similar to Oracle Forms

Tags: database, web-applications, oracleforms

I want to design a (web) interface where I can view, modify, insert records into my database along with many other features like use another table as reference. Basically like Oracle Forms & Reports.

What other apps have similar functionality?

I also want to know how frequently do enterprises use Oracle Forms - the application as well as the functionality provided in Oracle Application Express.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, people usually switch from Forms to Apex (if we're staying with Oracle). For reporting, I still use Reports Builder (and call those reports from Apex).

As of Forms still being used: most of our applications are written in Forms; much less number in ADF or Apex. Versions we (as a company) use are 10g and 12c.

Worldwide? Reading forum discussions, I've seen that people in India use Forms very frequently, and they still use client-server 6i version.

So, although there are rumors (that last at least 2 decades) that Oracle is going to *abandon* Forms, that didn't happen. Will it? I don't know. In my opinion, Forms is a very good tool whose main drawback is that applications developed in it look oldfashioned & ugly (more or less). Users prefer Apex-like applications nowadays.

Finally, note that this is a primarily opinion-based answer (because the question is such) so ... maybe the community will close it for further discussion. Personally, I hate seeing *anything* closed (here or on any other forum I visit) & hope that you'll get some more opinions.

Comment: Thanks! That was useful ... but yes, Forms is outdated. I also am not able to figure out dependencies of a Forms installation. I have been trying to do a standalone Forms Builder install on Windows 10 (12c), but I get listener port not activated errors when running a form. Could help me figure that out?

Comment: You're welcome. As of problems you have while running a form: that's another question, so - please, open a new topic and provide as many details as possible (including possible ORA- or FRM- errors you get). Right now, I have no idea what's going on (and can't promise I'll be able to assist at all, but someone else might).